# Encryption and decryption of SIPDROID VOIP calls in Android?

Tags: java, android, encryption, voip, sipdroid

I am working on VOIP calls integration in Android using [SIPDROID](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/). Here I want to encrypt data while sending and decrypt after receiving the data. I have gone through the code but confused as to which class file I should use for encryption and decryption of data.

Comment: CSipSimple (http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) is a free (GPL) SIP client for Android which supports TLS out of the box. It works great -- why not use it?

Comment: @wau: TLS is for SIP signalling encryption..while to encrypt media you need SRTP..does CSipSimple supports SRTP?

Comment: Yes it does. Afaik, for secure calling, you need both media and SIP encryption, since SRTP keys are exchanged using SIP.